# hide p:menubar with autoDisplay="false

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I have a `p:menubar` with `autoDisplay="false"` therefore the menu is opened only when I click on it.

I managed to hide the menu when the user click on iframe by calling from iframe a method like:

```
$("body").click(function(){
        top.closeMenu();
    });
```

And from top page I made:

```
function closeMenu(){
    $(".umfMenu").find(".ui-widget-content").hide();
    $(".umfMenu").find(".ui-state-hover").removeClass("ui-state-hover");
}
```

Now the menu is hidded with success but reappears onHover event because somehow his state is still active (and I want to show the menu only by clicking on it)

Do you know how instead of hide I can reset the state of the menu by beeing inactive?

My menu is:

```
<p:menubar  model="#{mainHeader.model}" autoDisplay="false" styleClass="umfMenu"/>
```

I'm using primefaces 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I would like to ask you but I don't have enough reputation yet.
Adiztu, have you tried to unbind hover event in p:menubar?

```
$(.umfMenu).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

I've read the documentation and I think this line can help you.

https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/menu/menu.js?r=7888

Comment: I tried you solution but I it still have the same behavior.